# Lock Pattern for android

Tags: android

**What i am trying to do:**
*A lock application*

**What i have tried**: 
*I tried to do this lock app with paint and canvas.*

**What is happening:**
*I am able to achieve the goal but usage is not smooth*

**What i am trying to find:**

1. What is the trajectory line shown in the image called.
2. How to use it.
3. Any samples of usage

---

[image]

Comment: Closing votes ? ..... I see no answers for this in comunity .... I can paste the code i did using paint ... but its is of no use ... !!!

Comment: Yes i know ... i am trying to do the same in android .... i posted a sample to show what i am refering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original view in AOSP is named LockPatternView, however I believe it is named so because it displays the (screen lock) pattern, instead of the pattern as a lock. Since this library is to provide the pattern as a locking mechanism, I'd prefer naming it PatternLock, and for simplicity， the view is renamed to PatternView [click here](https://github.com/DreaminginCodeZH/PatternLock)

or try this example [click here](https://github.com/geftimov/android-patternview)